# Blender 2.8 beta texture baking: Sub pixel sized vertical areas in UV map do not get always baked

Tags: texture-baking

I am baking color and lighting to texture with the baking feature under render panel. For some reason small sub pixel sized vertical areas in UV map do not get always baked on the texture. Is this a bug or a feature? Is there anything I can do about it other than manually expanding those areas or increasing texture resolution?

Comment: We could use some GIFs and a .blend file